# R string matching and replace

Tags: r, regex

Starting with the string `-theta[0] * x[0] * x[4] -theta[1] * x[1]`, I'd like capture `theta[.]` and replace with `exp(theta[.])` giving the final result as:

`-exp(theta[0]) * x[0] * x[4] -exp(theta[1]) * x[1]`

How do I accomplish this in R?

I tried the following to test by matching between `a`s as follows:

```
p <- c("abba", "abcdab")                                                      
gsub("\\(a[^a]*a\\)", "|\\1|", p)
```

I expected the output to be something like

```
|abba|
|abcda|b
```

But the output is

```
[1] "abba"   "abcdab"
```

What is the proper regex expression to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
gsub("(theta\\[\\d+\\])", "exp(\\1)", "-theta[0] * x[0] * x[4] -theta[1] * x[1]")
# [1] "-exp(theta[0]) * x[0] * x[4] -exp(theta[1]) * x[1]"
```

it matches `theta[.]` with any number of digits in the place of `.` and replaces it by `exp(theta[.])`.

Your attempt was good, you just didn't need to escape the brackets as they signify the group that you want to refer to later:

```
gsub("(a[^a]*a)", "|\\1|", p)
# [1] "|abba|"   "|abcda|b"
```